# Grid Grouping How to set checked "Show in groups" , manually

Tags: extjs4.1

I am using ExtJs 4.1

I have Grid with Grouping enabled. So there I can see the "Show in Group" menu on Grids header.

Now , my query is , If I have removed Grouping , i.e. unchecked the checkbox for "Show in Group". So Grouping gets removed. Right ?
Now If I have set the Grouping i.e. How I can set the check box to checked? manually i.e. through coding. Now by clicking on the check box.

Here by default we get Show in Gorups "**Checked**"
[image]

Now I have removed the **checked**
[image]

Now I want to checked this CheckBox , and show the Grouping using javascript coding

Please suggest How this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

To enable/disable grouping use `Ext.grid.feature.Grouping`:

```
var feature = Ext.Array.filter(grid.features, function(f) {
    return Ext.Array.contains(f.alias, 'feature.grouping');
})[0];
feature.enable();
feature.disable();
```

To change grouping field use `group` method on store:

```
store.group('FieldDataIndex');
```

Sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/czddU/